# how to catch a browser-blocked XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery ajax to perform a request but sometimes it is blocked by the browser (ie. when my site is running over https and it tries to make an external call to a http resource).

I use this code to make the request

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:    videoCallString,
        success: function(result) {
            //...if it isn't, we can't playback the video so skip next slide
            if (result != 1) {
                console.log('found no video_check on localhost so skip slide '+self.nextSlide);
                self.skip();                
            }
            else {
                //success, proceed as normal
                self.beforeComplete();
            }
        }, /*
        fail: function() {
                console.log('found no video_check on localhost so skip slide '+self.nextSlide);
                self.skip();
        }, */
        complete: function(xhr, data) {
            if (xhr.status != 200) {
                //we could not find the check-video file on localhost so skip next slide
                console.log('found no video_check on localhost so skip slide '+self.nextSlide);
                self.skip();                        
            }
            else {
                //success, proceed as normal
                self.beforeComplete();
            }
        }, //above would cause a double-slide-skip, I think. Removed for now, that should be trapped by the fail clause anyways.
        async: true
    });
```

But if a request is blocked, none of these events are triggered.

Would the fail event trigger if I didn't have it commented out? I did that because otherwise I get double skip() which is very undesirable...

Comment: Can you just use 'success' instead of the 'complete' callback?

Comment: Success is in there (see code sample) but never gets triggered when the browser blocks the request all together.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my testing goes, this is not possible to do.

In my case, I used a window variable to indicate whether page was loaded with chrome flag to allow this type of call or not, and only perform the ajax call if it was. Otherwise I just skip over the entire ajax call and go to the same result as a failed call.